# Distinguish API call from own app/webapp vs server

Tags: android, django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

I am using Django and we are planning on opening some of our API for 3rd party usage.

Till now we have been using DRF along with session authentication for our Django Web App and DRF with JWT for our Android application.

What I would like to know is whether the call is from our own app (webapp/android app) or from 3rd party apps (they can call from their own applications, which can be other webapps/phone apps). Is there any way this can be distinguished? We want to count the no.of 3rd party API call to our server.

Answer (score 0):

Your android app can add header `User-Agent` with app version. So you may distinguish requests. However it is not very reliable - as any web client can send such headers. Here you can sign your requests. Take URL add some secret value calculate md5/sha2 from this values and add to request. 
Protection is based on idea only you know secret value. It is ok for non-critical tasks but may be risky for financial  apps.

Comment: Got your point. Our API is part of our SaaS solution, our client can use both our app (web & phone) and their app (using 3rs party API). I would like to control the no. of 3rd party API calls per month. That's what the importance is. Any value (md5/sha2) stored in session cookies can be mal-used by bad users. Something like JWT for our app & long term token (like a one-time token generated by Google/Zoho for their APIs) for 3rd party app, would that help?

Comment: There's no way to distinguish absolutely. Suppose your android client was hacked - it your code which acts in very different way. Is it still "yours" or "theirs"?

Comment: I want to ask - that's final purpose of distinguishing? If statistics: how accurate it should be? You'll never get 100%.  but if 98-99% is enough - use first way. Mal users are just errors in statistics. If you want to provide better security - it's a wrong way. One should never rely on data from client. Server app should treat all on the same secure way.

Comment: I agree to your point. Let's think it in a different way. It's true that we cannot rely on client data, and never thought if "our" app gets compromised, whether it remains "ours" or "theirs". Thanks for your help.